# How to solve $1+\sum_{k=1}^r 3^k\binom{n}{k}$ (using, say, $ S\{n\} = \frac{a_1(1-r^n)}{1-r} $) so I can use it for large $r$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Following the solution to my previous post in:
[Counting unique element output from a product of combination](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053572/counting-unique-element-output-from-a-product-of-combination)

where the number of unique string-variants generated from a given string is:

$$
1+\sum_{k=1}^r 3^k\binom{n}{k}
$$

How to solve the summation so that I could use this formula for large $r$?

My attempt:
I try to solve it using a general formula:
$$
S\{n\} = \frac{a_1(1-r^n)}{1-r}
$$
for $a = 3$ and the common factor $r = 3$. But it turns out that is wrong since the formula above did not has anything to do with the binomial coefficient. Anyone can help?

Comment: I've edited the $\LaTeX$. Did you mean $S\{ n\}$ or something else?

Comment: What is an example of a large $r$?  Are $n$ and $r$ integers? positive?

Answer (score 2):

This sum does not have an elementary representation.  Let $f(r,n)$ be your sum.  By a [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system)
\begin{align*}
f(r,n) &= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^r 3^k \binom{n}{k} \\
    &= 4^n - 3^{r+1}\binom{n}{r+1}{}_2F_1(1,r-n+1;r+2;-3) 
\end{align*}

where ${}_2F_1$ is the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).  Even assuming $r$ and $n$ integers with $0 < r < n$, there are no simplifications to elementary functions.

For $1 \leq r < n$, use the sum.  This is easy as long as $n$ is not large.  You give no hints about the size of $n$ in your question.  Your prior post claims you are only interested in $1 \leq r \leq 4$, so this sum is nearly immediate.

For $r \geq n$, $f(r,n) = 4^n$.  This follows from your sum since $\binom{n}{n+1} = \binom{n}{n+2} = \cdots = 0$, so the sum cuts itself off after $r = n$, and a [standard identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Ordinary_generating_functions) (first one at that link, taking $x = 3$ and realizing the $k = 0$ term is the "$1+$" in $f$).  In the context of your previous post (not having read it in detail) -- once you've decided to replace *every* character in your string, then you have *any* $n$-length string you want from your 4 character alphabet, giving $4^n$ possibilities.

---

Digging through OP's referenced Question, he most likely intends $1 \leq r \leq 4$ and $r \leq n$.  These constraints appear nowhere in the current Question.  With those constraints ...
\begin{align*}
f(1,n) &= 1 + 3n  \text{,}  \\
f(2,n) &= 1 + 3n + \frac{9}{2}n(n-1)  \text{,}  \\
f(3,n) &= \frac{1}{2}(9n^2 -3n+2) + \frac{9}{2}n(n-1)(n-2)  \text{, and}  \\
f(4,n) &= \frac{1}{2}(9n^3 - 18 n^2 + 15 n + 2) + \frac{27}{8}n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)  \text{.}
\end{align*}

For example, $f(4,10\,000) = 33\,734\,252\,812\,372\,501$.  I note this because representing such quantities in a programming language as precise integers (instead of imprecise floating point approximations) can require some effort.  Letting $r$ and $n$ be "large" necessitates this effort.  If you intend to generate these numbers in a programming language, it would help to know which language you are targetting.

---

Just testing for timing, I get the complete set of results for $n = 10\,000$ in about 180 ms using this code:

```
import itertools
import time

class sumterm:
    """Iterator to produce terms of a specific sum counting replaced strings."""
    def __init__(self, nInit):
        # Rememember: Iterators start in a "prior to the first element" state 
        # and are expected to yield the first element on the first call to 
        # __next__().
        self.n = nInit
        self.k = 0
        self.term = 1  # 3^k binom(n,k) = 1 binom(n,0) = 1, when k = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        try: self.n
        except NameError: raise ValueError("sumterm objects must be initialized before iterating.")

        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.k < self.n:
            # 3^(k+1) binom(n,k+1) = 3^k binom(n,k) * 3(n-k)/(k+1)
            # Integer division ( // ) is safe because divisibility is ensured.
            self.term = self.term * 3*(self.n - self.k) // (self.k+1)
            self.k += 1
            return self.term
        else:
            raise StopIteration

n = 10000
tBefore = time.time()
terms = list(iter(sumterm(n)))
partialSums = [1+x for x in itertools.accumulate(terms) ]
tAfter = time.time()

print("For n = ", n, ", k = 1 .. 11: ",  partialSums[:11])
print("Took",  tAfter - tBefore,  " seconds.")
```

Don't bother trying to print the last few terms.  $4^{10\,000}$ is too large to usefully look at.

Note that `partialSums[k-1]` is $f(k,n)$ for $k \leq n$.

---

\begin{align*}
f(1,n) &= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^1 3^k \binom{n}{k}  \\
&= 1 + 3^1 \binom{n}{1}  \\
&= 1 + 3 n  \text{, } \\
f(2,n) &= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^2 3^k \binom{n}{k}  \\
&= 1 + 3^1 \binom{n}{1} + 3^2 \binom{n}{2} \\
&= 1 + 3 n + 9\frac{n(n-1)}{2}  \text{, } \\
f(3,n) &= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^3 3^k \binom{n}{k}  \\
&= 1 + 3^1 \binom{n}{1} + 3^2 \binom{n}{2} + 3^3 \binom{n}{3} \\
&= 1 + 3 n + 9\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + 27\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}  \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(2 + 6n + 9n(n-1)) + \frac{9}{2}n(n-1)(n-2)  \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(9n^2 - 3 n + 2) + \frac{9}{2}n(n-1)(n-2)  \text{,}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
f(4,n) &= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^4 3^k \binom{n}{k}  \\
&= 1 + 3^1 \binom{n}{1} + 3^2 \binom{n}{2} + 3^3 \binom{n}{3} + 3^4 \binom{n}{4}  \\
&= 1 + 3 n + 9\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + 27\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} + 81\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}  \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(2 + 6n + 9n(n-1) + 9n(n-1)(n-2)) + \frac{27}{8}n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)  \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(9 n^3 - 18 n^2 + 15 n + 2) + \frac{27}{8}n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)  \text{.} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I only intend to use $1 \leq r < 4$ since the substituents only composed of four characters. I am just curious whether the formula $1+\sum_{k=1}^r 3^k\binom{n}{k}$ could be simplified to elementary function so that it could be used for n let's say 10,000 and r at most equals to n. Sum it up for such n and r would be cumbersome.

Comment: @VicBrown : So it can't be simplified to an elementary function.  Perhaps it can be approximated with something elementary.  Would an approximation (and if so, how precise and accurate would you require) suffice?

Comment: @VicBrown : Officially, answers to questions on this site are evaluated (by the crowds) as answers to the Question as asked.  Your Question does not include the constraints $1 \leq r \leq 4$ and $r \leq n$, which I infer from your referenced question.  Since those are not part of the current question, they cannot be assumed in an Answer.

Comment: @VicBrown : As the extension to my question shows, for $n = 10\,000$, $f(r,n)$ quickly exceeds usual integral representations in some programming languages.  If you intend to compute these with software, it would be helpful to know what your targetted software is.

Comment: Your solution above and it is similar to what I solve using polynomial equation for r = 1 to 4 and n = 3 to 10, where:
$$
f(1,n) = 3n + 1
$$
$$
f(2,n) = \frac{9}{2}n^2 - \frac{3}{2}n + 1
$$
$$
f(3,n) = \frac{27}{6}n^3 - 9n^2 + 15n + 1
$$
$$
f(4,n) = \frac{27}{8}n^4 - \frac{63}{4}n^3 + \frac{225}{8}n^2 - \frac{51}{4}n + 1
$$
I do not intend to apply such equation into my program (I am using Python 3 by the way). I just only wanted to provide mathematical proof that a list of unique string variants generated by the program is correct.

Comment: The code I've just edited in generates all $f(k,10000)$ values in about 180 milliseconds on my hardware.

Comment: Thanks for writing a code that could confirm $f(r, n)$ function. By the way, could you show me how to arrive to these equations:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(1,n) &= 1 + 3n  \text{,}  \\
f(2,n) &= 1 + 3n + \frac{9}{2}n(n-1)  \text{,}  \\
f(3,n) &= \frac{1}{2}(9n^2 -3n+2) + \frac{9}{2}n(n-1)(n-2)  \text{, and}  \\
f(4,n) &= \frac{1}{2}(9n^3 - 18 n^2 + 15 n + 2) + \frac{27}{8}n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
$$

from:
$$
1+\sum_{k=1}^r 3^k\binom{n}{k}
$$

My head was not able take me there...

Comment: I don't know how you can not know this, but I've added yet another computation to this Answer that is not part of your Question.  You do know, for instance, $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in asymptotics:

$$\begin{align}
s(n,r)&=\sum_{k=1}^r 3^k\binom{n}{k}\\
&=2^n\sum_{k=1}^r 3^k\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}\\
&\approx \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n /2}} \int_0^r 3^x \exp\left( -\frac{2}{n}(x-n/2)^2 \right)
 dx \\
  \end{align}$$

If $r > 0.78 n$ we can apply [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) and get the first order approximation:

$$ \frac{\log (s(n,r))}{n} \to  \log(2) + \frac{\log^2(3)+ 4 \log 3}{8}\approx 1.393$$

For smaller $r$ , a similar approximation can be obtained (tell me if you are interested) but it involves both $(n,r)$ variables.